# Trying to get the double values out of an NSMutableArray full of NSDate objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, xcode

I'm creating a program that adds the current date/time to an NSMutableArray every time a button is pressed. I'm then trying to get the double values of the times into another NSMutableArray. Ultimately, I'd like to use those double values to determine the average time between them. Here is what I have so far:

IBAction code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender {

    _currentTapTime = [NSDate date];
    [_tapTimeData addObject:_currentTapTime];

    _tapCountInt++;
    _tapCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_tapCountInt];

}
```

My code trying to get the time into another array as double values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_tapTimeData count]; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        NSTimeInterval interval = [[_tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i] timeIntervalSinceDate:[_tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i]];
        [_intervalNumber initWithDouble:interval];
        [_tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:_intervalNumber];
     } else {
         NSTimeInterval interval = [[_tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i] timeIntervalSinceDate:[_tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i-1]];
         [_intervalNumber initWithDouble:interval];
         [_tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:_intervalNumber];
      }
}
```

I'm getting null data and can't get the double values out of the array.

Essentially, I'd like the program to do the following:

1. The user taps the button.
2. The program records the current time for that tap.
3. When the user stops tapping, the double values indicating the difference between each tap ends up in a new array.
4. I will later calculate the average time (in milliseconds) between each tap, and do some other calculations like the variance and standard deviation of the time between the taps.

Thank you!

Comment: _intervalNumber is coming out null?

Comment: Make your code more readable: [_tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:@(interval)]. Then use a name for that array that is actually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

```
[_intervalNumber initWithDouble:interval];
[_tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:_intervalNumber];
```

should be this:

```
_intervalNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:interval];
[_tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:_intervalNumber];
```

**Code:**

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSDate *currentTapTime;
    NSMutableArray *tapTimeData;
    int tapCountInt;
    IBOutlet UILabel *tapCount;
    NSNumber *intervalNumber;
    NSMutableArray *tapTimeDataAsDouble;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tapCountInt = 0;

    tapTimeData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tapTimeDataAsDouble = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

- (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender {

    currentTapTime = [NSDate date];
    [tapTimeData addObject:currentTapTime];


    NSLog(@"%@", tapTimeData);

    tapCountInt++;
    tapCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)tapCountInt];
}


- (IBAction)tapAverage:(id)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < [tapTimeData count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"################%d", i);

        if (i == 0) {
            NSTimeInterval interval = [[tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i] timeIntervalSinceDate:[tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i]];
            intervalNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:interval];
            [tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:intervalNumber];
        } else {
            NSTimeInterval interval = [[tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i] timeIntervalSinceDate:[tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i-1]];
            intervalNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:interval];
            [tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:intervalNumber];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", tapTimeDataAsDouble);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I wanted to get the time between each tap, and this does it by using the NSTimeInterval. Now I'll take these numbers and look for my mean, variance, and standard deviation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you initiate the array _tapTimeDataAsDouble and _tapTimeData
2. Created a similar function as your code.

[image: Displaying the interval]

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that first step value, which is always going to be 0?

> NSTimeInterval interval = [[_tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i]
>   timeIntervalSinceDate:[_tapTimeData objectAtIndex:i]];

This should do what you need. The outcome array will contain n-1 objects instead.

```
for (int i = 1; i < [_tapTimeData count]; i++) {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [_tapTimeData[i] timeIntervalSinceDate:_tapTimeData[i-1]];
    [_tapTimeDataAsDouble addObject:@(intervalNumber)];
}
```

Comment: If you really need that 0 value, just add it manually and without code duplication